# Check if a node with a key exists in a list

Tags: firebase

#### The problem

I need to have a special check in existed firebase data structure and want to know if it is possible (or any work around).

So current structure is:

```
{
   groups: {
      group1: { name: "Group one" }
      group2: { name: "Group two" }
   },
   members: {
      group1: { 
         "some@email,com": true,
         "another@email,com": true
      },
      group2: { "some@email,com": true }
   }
}
```

What I need and can do easily:

1. Get all users in a specific group
2. Add a user to any specific group
3. Remove a user from any specific group

But I have no idea how to make a check: **if a user with some email is a member of any group.**

Number of groups and members can be quite big so i do not want to load all members objects and check manually.

#### My not optimal solution

The only way I could find is to add one more object `users` and keep available groups there. Like so:

```
{
    users: {
       "some@email,com": {
           groups: {
              group1: true,
              group2: true
           }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case I can do the check without any problems, but will add one more request to add/remove actions (add email to members and add groupID to user; remove email from members and remove groupID from user).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there some problem with checking the node directly? Just doing a `value` call on members/group1/some@email,com and seeing if the value is `true`? Unclear what your goal is here.

Comment: @Kato I think the idea is to see if an email exists in *any* group, not just a specific one?

Comment: @Jay you are right about the idea. I do not know the groupID and i need to check if email is in _ANY_ group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done

For example, given this structure

```
Members
  Group_0
    ben@thing,com: "value"
    jerry@thing,com: @"value"
    frank@thing,com: @"value"
  Group_1
    elmo@thing,com: "value"
    linda@thing,com: "value"
```

We construct a query as follows (ObjC)

```
FQuery *q1 = [ref queryOrderedByChild:@"elmo@thing,com"];
FQuery *q2 = [q1 queryEqualToValue:@"value"];

[q2 observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);
}];
```

and the query returns

```
  Group_1
    elmo@thing,com: "value"
    linda@thing,com: "value"
```

(updated info)

The downside of the above is the key you are looking up is dynamic (the email) and there won't be a rule in place for indexing on that key - so Firebase will complain that

```
Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn":....etc
```

Here's a possible solution: Use a node structure like this

```
emails_node
   random_node_name_0
      email: "jerry@thing.com"
      group: "group_0"
   random_node_name_1
      email: "linda@thing.com"
      group: "group_1"
   random_node_name_2
      email: "elmo@thing.com"
      group: "group_1"
```

and a set of rules

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "emails_node": {
      ".indexOn": "email"
    }
  }
```

the random_node_name_x is a Firebase reference created by childByAutoId (ObjC)

the query then becomes

```
FQuery *q1 = [ref queryOrderedByChild:@"email"];
FQuery *q2 = [q1 queryEqualToValue:@"elmo@thing.com"];
```

the result is

```
email = "elmo@thing.com";
group = group1;
```

The advantages here are two fold:

1) The query returns both the email and group so you can not only check for duplicates but also tells us which group it's in (if needed)

2) The actual email value can be used instead of parsing/changing the email from      . (dot) to ,

Comment: thanks for the trick, but in this case i will have an index warning from firebase. It will say `Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "elmo@thing,com" at /members ...`. I do not think i can live with this warning as number of groups and members can be quite big. Do you have any thoughts about this indexing problem?