# How to compare answer of selected row and retrieve the answer from firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a wine searcher app. Basically, I use food pairing for the wines. The user chooses for his favourite food. I have my firebase database storing the data of wines labelled with name and type of that certain wine. Here is my json structure in the firebase.

```
Wines:
  Wine1: 
   Name: Catena Zapata Malbec
   Type: Bold Red
  Wine2:
.......... etc.
```

I have another previous view controller for selecting favourite food. For example, if user choose red meat, the relevant typing would be "Bold Red".
So, I do a switch case, for case:1 (which is red meat being chosen), the reference go into the "Type" and search for "Bold Red", and finally print out all the relevant result of that red wine.

```
class Wine: NSObject{
    var name: String?
    var type: String?
    var foodChoice: String?
}


class ResultViewController: UITableViewController {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var refHandle: UInt!
var wineList = [Wine]()
var intPassed: Int!
let cellId = "cellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Results" 
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    fetchWine() 
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return wineList.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
    cell.textLabel?.text = wineList[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
}


func fetchWine(){
    switch intPassed {
    case 0:
        refHandle = ref.child("Wines").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let wine = Wine()
                wine.name = dictionary["name"] as! String?
                wine.type = dictionary["type"] as! String?

                wine.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.wineList.append(wine)

                print (wine.name, wine.type)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    case 1:
        refHandle = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "Type").queryEqual(toValue: "Bold Red").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let wine = Wine()
            wine.name = dictionary["name"] as! String?

            wine.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            self.wineList.append(wine)

            print (wine.name)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
    })
default:
        print("nothing")

    }
}  
}
```

I can print the data for the case 0. But I cannot get the data I wanted if I want to compare the answer of type chosen to the type in the database. Is it the referencing for the refHandle wrong?

Here is the result printed for case 0. It is just for me to make sure the firebase is working. The other options are just other wines in my database.

```
0
Optional("Catena Zapata Malbec") Optional("Bold Red")
Optional("Merlot") Optional("Medium Red")
Optional("Pinot Noir") Optional("Light Red")
```

Please help! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You don't need intPassed in the fetchWine function (it's not valid anyway unless it's class defined, and in that case it would be self.intPassed). Loose the DispatchQueue as they are not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's answer this with with a structure, code to retrieve particular types of wine and a thought.

Assume the customer is having a meaty or spicy dinner and wants some wine options to go with that. They know bold red is the way to go

Your wine structure looks like this; keeping in mind that the parent keys should be generated with childByAutoId()

```
wines
  wine_id_0
    name: "Joseph Phelps Insignia"
    type: "Bold Red"
  wine_id_1
    name: "Heitz Cellers: Martha's Vineyard"
    type: "Bold Red"
  wine_id_2
    name: "Seasmoke Southing"
    type: "Fruity Red"
```

Then we need a class, or a struct in the case, that we can store in an array which is the dataSource for our tableView, and then the array to hold the wines when we load them in.

```
struct WineStruct {
    var key = ""
    var name = ""
    var type = ""
}

var wineArray = [WineStruct]()
```

Finally, a verbose code snippet to read in (in this case) all of the Bold Red wines.

```
        let wineTypeToQuery = "Bold Red"
        let wineRef = ref.child("wines")
        let queryRef = wineRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "type")
                              .queryEqual(toValue: wineTypeToQuery)
        queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let wineDict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
                var wine = WineStruct()
                wine.name = wineDict["name"] as! String
                wine.type = wineDict["type"] as! String
                wine.key = snap.key
                self.wineArray.append(wine)
            }

            //here you would call tableView.reloadData()
            //do not use DispatchQueue!
            for wine in self.wineArray { //print the wines as a test
                let aWine = wine as! WineStruct
                let name = aWine.name
                let type = aWine.type
                print("\(name)  \(type)")
            }
        })
```

and the resultant output

```
Joseph Phelps Insignia  Bold Red
Heitz Cellers: Martha's Vineyard  Bold Red
```

This code will handle loading all of the Bold Red wines in and whatever other associated data is kept in each wine child node. The above code can be condensed considerably (about 1/2 the number of lines) but I left it verbose for readability.

A thought:

You may want to consider a different structure because different wines can go with different foods.

For example:

```
wines
  wine_id_0
    name: "Joseph Phelps Insignia"
    type: "Bold Red"
    pairs_with:
      steak: true
      ribs: true
  wine_id_1
    name: "Heitz Cellers: Martha's Vineyard"
    type: "Bold Red"
    pairs_with:
      steak: true
      pork: true
  wine_id_2
    name: "Seasmoke Southing"
    type: "Fruity Red"
    pairs_with:
      cheese: true
      fish: true
    aromatics:
      spicey: true
```

With this structure, we don't assume the customer knows that a Bold Red goes with a steak. They can select 'steak' and we narrow the results that way.

Of course you could further refine the search as a wine that pairs well with a rib-eye (which has a high fat content and really needs higher alcohol to cut through it) may not be the same wine that pairs with a Filet.

I threw in aromatics on the last wine as that can further narrow the search field - if the user is ordering a light flakey fish, that can typically call for a Chardonnay or Sauvignon Blanc. However, if it's a presented in a blackened (spicey) style, a Pinot can often be a winner.

Hope that helps! Love the app concept!

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed suggestion!!! 
That structure really helps because I am also thinking about getting different food for users. I have also figured out another method to do so. I tried to search for the key and value in the dictionary of wines, if I get the value "Bold Red", and I print out the name of that particular wine and it works too!

Comment: I will try your solutions too and the thought is really helpful. Thanks and cheers ;)

Comment: @ManPingCheung If the answer helped, please accept it so other users can benefit as well. :-)

Comment: Hey man, I think your code should work, but I got another error.

[FirebaseDatabase] Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "type" at /wines to your security rules for better performance

I had already changed the database rules to:{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "Wines":{
        ".indexOn": "type"
    }
  }
}

Comment: @ManPingCheung That's not really a critical error, but should be addressed in the future. See the answer to [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157080/check-if-a-node-with-a-key-exists/31173552#31173552) and also the documentation from Firebase about using indexes [Index Your Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data). And don't forget to accept the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

What I've observed is that your `refHandle` seems to be right. But you access the data wrong in the observe block.

### Solution

Your `dictionary` in case 1 looks like that:

```
["Wine1": {
   name = "Catena Zapata Malbec";
   type = "Bold Red";
}]
```

That means, you need to access another dictionary to access only the name `Catena Zapata Malbec` of your wine in case 1 like this

```
case 1:
    refHandle = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "Type").queryEqual(toValue: "Bold Red").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

          // Here access your name of the wine in the node
          if let wine1Dictionary = dictionary["Wine1"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let wine = Wine()
            wine.name = wine1Dictionary["name"] as! String?


            wine.setValuesForKeys(wine1Dictionary)
            self.wineList.append(wine)

            print(wine.name)
          }
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code? It fails in a couple of ways in that it doesn't handle (well) multiple Bold Red's, it's overly complex, the setValuesForKeys is questionable in this use case, and there's no need for the DispatchQueue call. Also, these no need for the refHandle, although it doesn't affect the operation.

Comment: Tested the code regarding to access the data with the given structure from the OP. But I didn't test the whole logic with the switch case, the usage of the refHandle and also I haven't thought further regarding multiple cases. You're right, there is no need for the DispatchQueue call

Comment: The biggest issue that it doesn't address the question *print out all the relevant result of that red wine.* Your code only handles one specific red wine, Wine1, and more importantly if Wine1 is actually a childByAutoId() key (which it should be) where the key node is not known beforehand, it fails. The OP wants all the results loaded into an array to be used as a datasource which will then be used to present to the user all of the wines in the database that are a good pairing for the selected food, not just one. Can you update your answer to address the OP's question?

Comment: I did not try to run with multiple "Bold Red", I may try it soon!
Thanks for the answer too bro!